# Installation wizard for a custom module Odoo

Tags: odoo

I just create a simple wizard inside my custom module for Odoo. I called using a button but i need he appears when install the module Any suggestion ? i'm new in odoo world

Comment: Please provide more clear and brief details. Not getting clear idea from wha you have written.

Comment: like in installation of accounting when you choose the chart of account and currency, i want a wizard appears when install my custom module sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [see how this is done here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/account_installer.xml). Basically a small `ir.actions.todo` object is created in XML, pointing to the action that is supposed to be executed:

```
<record id="example_configuration_installer" model="ir.actions.todo">
    <field name="action_id" ref="your_action_to_be_executed"/>
    <field name="type">automatic</field>
</record>
```